# C# SQL null convert to-from, any issues with this?

Tags: c#, sql, null, nullable

This seems to work for me, but was wondering if there are any issues with it

```
 class Test
    {
        public int PKId { get; set; }
        public string RequiredString { get; set; }
        public int RequiredInt { get; set; }
        public decimal RequiredMoney { get; set; }
        public bool RequiredBool { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
        public string NullableString { get; set; }
        public int? NullableInt { get; set; }
        public decimal? NullableMoney { get; set; }
        public bool? NullableBool { get; set; }
        public DateTime? NullableDate { get; set; }
    }
```

The testDatabase matches the class as far as nulls are concerned.

```
  static internal T NullConvertFromDB<T>(object value) 
        {
            if (value.Equals(DBNull.Value))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            else
            {
                return (T)value;
            }
        }

        static internal object NullConvertToDB<T>(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return System.DBNull.Value;
            else
                return (T)value;
        }
```

While retrieving data I use

```
 Test test = new Test();
                        test.PKId = dr.GetInt32(0);
                        test.RequiredString = dr.GetString(1);
                        test.RequiredInt = dr.GetInt32(2);
                        test.RequiredMoney = (decimal)dr.GetSqlMoney(3);
                        test.RequiredBool = dr.GetBoolean(4);
                        test.RequiredDate = dr.GetDateTime(5);
                        test.NullableString = NullConvertFromDB<string>(dr[6]);
                        test.NullableInt = NullConvertFromDB<int?>(dr[7]);
                        test.NullableMoney = NullConvertFromDB<decimal?>(dr[8]);
                        test.NullableBool = NullConvertFromDB<bool?>(dr[9]);
                        test.NullableDate = NullConvertFromDB<DateTime?>(dr[10]);
```

And inserting I use

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequiredString", test.RequiredString);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequiredInt", test.RequiredInt);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequiredMoney", test.RequiredMoney);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequiredBool", test.RequiredBool);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequiredDate", test.RequiredDate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NullableString", NullConvertToDB<string>(test.NullableString));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NullableInt", NullConvertToDB<int?>(test.NullableInt));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NullableMoney", NullConvertToDB<decimal?>(test.NullableMoney));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NullableBool", NullConvertToDB<bool?>(test.NullableBool));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NullableDate", NullConvertToDB<DateTime?>(test.NullableDate));
```

This works great but was wondering if there is anything I need to be aware of before I implement in in my DAL.

Regards

_Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a minor thing, `is` would probably be more efficient:

```
if (value == null || value is DBNull) {... null code...}
```

as a *second* thought, I don't like the fact that if `T=int` you will get `0` for a null; I'd want an error. I'd be tempted to use:

```
return (T)(object)null;
```

which should work for reference types and `Nullable<T>` correctly, and raise an error for `int` etc.

---

In `ConvertToDb`, the `return (T)value;` is redundant, since you are actually returning `object`; you may as well just:

```
return value ?? DBNull.Value;
```

(in both cases)

---

So:

```
    static internal T NullConvertFromDB<T>(object value) 
    {
        if (value == null || value is DBNull)
        {
            return (T)(object)null;
        }
        return (T)value;
    }

    static internal object NullConvertToDB<T>(object value)
    {
        return value ?? DBNull.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have a question about if T=int you'll get 0 for null. Is that just a way to make sure the method performs correctly if the user/me used NullConvertFromDB<int> instead of <int?>

Comment: @Eric - yes; if somebody asked for `NullConvertFromDB<int>` against a `null`, I'd want that to throw an exception.

Comment: got it thanks. So now would I need to wrap my reader in a try and catch the NullReferenceEX there

Comment: @Eric - no; don't add an exception handler; that scenario represents a boneheaded exception (see [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)) - let the exception show itself to the developer.